# Exchange rate currency format setting in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, currency

I have an exchange rate application in flutter, but I want to make the currency format the same as below, how can I do it?

My Code :

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import '../Utils.dart';

class CurrencyInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
  TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
if (newValue.selection.baseOffset == 0) {
  print(true);
  return newValue;
}

double value = double.parse(newValue.text);

final formatter = NumberFormat("#,##0", "tr-TR");

String newText = formatter.format(value);
print(newText);
return newValue.copyWith(
    text: newText,
    selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newText.length));
 }
}
```

I want to do

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved. works great.[image]

```
library currency_text_input_formatter;

import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

/// The `symbol` argument is used to symbol of NumberFormat.
/// Put '\$' for symbol
///
/// The `locale` argument is used to locale of NumberFormat.
/// Put 'en' or 'es' for locale
///
/// The `decimalDigits` argument is used to decimalDigits of NumberFormat.
/// Defaults `decimalDigits` is 2.
class CurrencyTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    if (newValue.text.isEmpty) {
      return newValue.copyWith(text: '');
    } else if (newValue.text == ".") {
      return newValue.copyWith(
        text: '0.00',
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 2),
      );
    } else {
      NumberFormat f = NumberFormat("#,###,###.00", "en_US");
      double newNumber = 0;
      if ((!newValue.text.contains(".")) && oldValue.text.contains('.')) {
        String tempString = newValue.text.replaceAll(f.symbols.GROUP_SEP, '');
        tempString = tempString.substring(0, tempString.length - 2) +
            "." +
            tempString.substring(tempString.length - 2);
        newNumber = double.parse(tempString);
      } else {
        newNumber = double.parse(newValue.text
            .replaceAll(f.symbols.GROUP_SEP, '')
            .replaceAll("..", '.'));
      }
      String newString = f.format(newNumber);
      int cursorPosition = 0;
      if (oldValue.text.length > newString.length) {
        cursorPosition = -1;
      } else if (oldValue.text.length < newString.length) {
        cursorPosition = 1;
      } else {
        if (oldValue.text.replaceAll(f.symbols.GROUP_SEP, '').length >
            newValue.text.replaceAll(f.symbols.GROUP_SEP, '').length) {
          cursorPosition = -1;
          if (newString == "0.00" && oldValue.selection.baseOffset == 0) {
            newString = "";
          }
        } else if (oldValue.text.replaceAll(f.symbols.GROUP_SEP, '').length <
            newValue.text.replaceAll(f.symbols.GROUP_SEP, '').length) {
          cursorPosition = 1;
        } else if (oldValue.selection.extentOffset >
            oldValue.selection.baseOffset) {
          cursorPosition =
              oldValue.selection.baseOffset - oldValue.selection.extentOffset;
          newString =
              newString.substring(0, oldValue.selection.baseOffset - 1) +
                  newString.substring(oldValue.selection.baseOffset + 1);
          newNumber = double.parse(newString
              .replaceAll(f.symbols.GROUP_SEP, '')
              .replaceAll("..", '.'));
          newString = f.format(newNumber);
          if (newString == "0.00" && oldValue.selection.baseOffset == 0) {
            newString = "";
          }
        }
      }
      return TextEditingValue(
        text: newString,
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
            offset: oldValue.selection.extent.offset +
                cursorPosition +
                (f.symbols.GROUP_SEP.allMatches(newString).length -
                    f.symbols.GROUP_SEP.allMatches(oldValue.text).length)),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) actually provides you a way to do so.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

final moneyText = 1000;
NumberFormat.simpleCurrency().format(moneyText);
```

If you are already using translation, you should have intl already.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with  [flutter_masked_text](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_masked_text) package it can do exactly the same.